# Use the TCS3200 color sensor without the included LEDs

Tags: sensors

just a quick question. I want to know if it is possible to use the TCS3200 color sensor without the 4 LEDs included on the breakout board. I want to get the sky colors. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photodiodes in the device itself have filters so it should *theoretically* be possible to use it without auxiliary light sources. Note, however, that the green and blue sensors have *two* sensitivity peaks and so using it outdoors without an infrared filter is not advised.

Comment: So how could I use the sensor without LEDs? I want to operate it using solar power and can't waste any energy. Can I just bridge them? Will I damage anything by doing that? Also is there any DIY infrared filter that I could build use with materials normal people have at home?